# Google Earth-Unsupported graphics card

Tags: graphics, software-installation, 3d, google-earth

I've just installed Google Earth on my PC,which runs Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
When I open Google Earth,a window pop-ups and says:"Unsupported Graphics Card
Your graphics card does nor meet the minimum spec required to run Google Earth,which is a 3D accelerated card with shader support.It is strongly recommended that you try running Google Earth on a different machine or in a different rendering mode or upgrade to a newer graphics card.You may continue,but the application is unlikely to work."
Maybe you'll say:"Buy a better graphics card!",but I used Google Earth on this machine an year ago,when I had Windows 7 & everything worked well,so my graphics card is good enough.
The Linux version has bigger requirements than the Windows one or what???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Google Earth is now running, but I'm getting this error when I try to search for a location: invalid url. To get Google Earth to work I went back to www.google.com/earth/ and picked my 32-bit .deb installation file, there's also a 64-bit .deb file. Then I noticed the "Advanced" tab above and clicked it. There is a choice for an older version 7.0 instead of 7.1, so I downloaded it. Instead of a .deb file it's a .bin file.

I then tried over and over again to find the right application to open it. After several non-working choices and much frustration I tried again and chose to run with "gedit". It took forever, but it loaded it and it's working. I had to look and click on "bin" and then open. I hope this helps you!

Comment: Yes,it worked,thanks!And sorry for accepting your answer so late,I had to work with other Linux distributions and forgot about this problem after I updated to 14.04,but I runned an Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine to check it out.